# Windows 10 SSD Stops Booting

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

**Problem:**
Dell PC stops booting from the SSD.

**Background:**
2013 Dell Precision Tower with Xeon processor and HHD. Over a year ago, cloned HHD to Samsung SSD EVO 850, no problems. Then updated from Windows 7 to 10, no problem. Left HHD as 2nd drive.

Today, restarted PC and getting BSOD. Got message that can't boot from SSD.

**Here's what I tried:**
I opened it up, unplugged the HHD (thought maybe it died and screwed up the BIOS somehow) and tried booting up, still no dice.

Took out the SSD, plugged into different PC with USB adapter, shows up perfectly, everything looks fine with the SSD. All files are there. But Samsung Magician didn't detect it as valid for some reason (maybe cuz through USB).

Anyway, I put it back in my PC, put in a Windows Installation Media DVD, and tried repairing.

1. Startup Repair - didn't work.
2. System Restore gave me the error message:

   > To use System Restore, you must specify which Windows Installation to restore.
   >
   > Restart this computer, select an operating system, and then select System Restore.

But I can't select an OS

3. System Image Recovery also didn't help
4. Neither did "Go Back to Previous Version"
5. So, I opened the command prompt from there:

   a. Tried using `bootrec` per [this](https://pureinfotech.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows-10/) article. `/fixmbr` and `/fixboot` both gave me an error that `The system cannot find the path specified`.

   b. I also tried `chkdsk` but it gave me an error that it can't `run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected`.

   c. *Edit:* forgot to mention, I also tried SFC /scannow, also didn't work.

What should I do? I'm at my wits end. I have a feeling this may have been caused by malware but not sure how that helps me. Not even sure how I can do a factory reset in this situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

***Edit 2:*** I connected the SSD to another PC and ran `diskpart`, here's a screenshot:
[Diskpart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUoh.png)

Comment: Whether you in correct path. I mean x:\sources\ for example

Comment: @Techie Gossip Not sure what you mean, yes I am in the `x:\sources\ `

Comment: SFC /scannow command will help u.

Comment: At which point did you determine this was a "can't boot" issue that needed the type of repairs you are trying? You said the system is blue screening on startup. That is not a boot problem. What is the actual error you receive during boot?

Comment: @Appleoddity good point, forgot to mention. Originally there was the blue screen with the message that boot device didn't load, then when I took out the HHD it just shows a black screen with the message in white that `No bootable devices `

Comment: @TechieGossip No it won't, I tried that. Forgot to mention it in my post. It gave me an error.

Comment: Can you plug the HDD back in and update your question with both exact error messages you receive when it is plugged in and when it is not? It helps to know the current status of your system and how we got to where we are now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from USB. The drive locked it seems.

1. Copy all the files from your downloaded ISO you've used to install Windows 10 to a USB stick. Make it boot able using Rufus tool.
2. Boot from that USB stick and press Shift+F10 when Windows 10 setup WinPE shell starts. It enter cmd prompt

NOTE: Make sure c: is your boot drive with your OS by running

```
x:\>diskpart

DISKPART> list disk

DISKPART> select disk 0

DISKPART> list volume

DISKPART> exit
```

3. In the command prompt type:

```
x:\>chkdsk /f /v /r /b /offlinescanandfix c:
```

Comment: Thanks. I did DISKPART > list disk and it says "There are no fixed disks to show"

Comment: You told you have conncted tat ssd to other system.. what did u see there?. did u see your partitions? Any partitions is having is files?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I booted using SSD and Windows Media, launched command prompt from Troubleshooting menu, and did DISKPART which yielded nothing. Should I try connecting the SSD to a different PC through USB and do DISKPART there?

Comment: When u connect the ssd to different system.. what u see in disk management.. can u see the disk and it's partitions

Comment: Thanks. I did it, see screenshot in my original question, I added an edit

Comment: Go to drive G: and run chkdsk /f /r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65563/discussion-between-josh-d-and-techie-gossip).